# The requested task could not be executed on \Forms\AB\DataSources\XY\Methods\displayOption

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm developing a new ListPage and have switched it from a table Datasource to a query datasource. Now when I try to modify the displayOption method I get an errorlog message:

> The requested task could not be executed on \Forms\AB\DataSources\XY\Methods\displayOption The operation could not be performed.

When I try to add a displayOption method to the second table in the query, I get no problems.

Comment: Please check the following link https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/thedynamicsblog/archive/2014/03/12/alternate-of-displayoption-method-on-list-page

Comment: Also you can try at your own risk the following 'solution' http://www.fatihdemirci.net/index.php/2013/05/20/how-to-change-grid-row-color-in-listpage-form-in-dynamics-ax-2012/